# Cockroach DB failing to create client certificate

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, cockroachdb

I have installed Cockroach DB on my Linux (WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04) using the tutorial [here](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v20.2/secure-a-cluster.html).

However, when I try to create the client certificate and key pair for the root user in Step 1.4, I am getting the following error:

```
W210412 14:47:47.996624 1 security/certificate_loader.go:356  error finding key for certs/node.crt: key file certs/node.key has permissions -rwxrwxrwx, exceeds -rwx------
```

ERROR: failed to generate client certificate and key: key file certs/node.key has permissions -rwxrwxrwx, exceeds -rwx------
Failed running "cert create-client"
Consequently, I am unable to start the cluster in the next step.

Answer (score 2):

CockroachDB requires key files to have sane permissions (owner only).
However, the windows subsystem for linux has an odd handling of file permissions (see [this WSL doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/file-permissions) for more details).

You have two options:

- figure out how to change file permissions on WSL2, if possible
- tell CockroachDB to skip key file permissions

The latter is described in the [certificates documentation](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v20.2/cockroach-cert#client-key-and-certificates):

> Keys (files ending in .key) must not have group or world permissions
> (maximum permissions are 0700, or rwx------). This check can be
> disabled by setting the environment variable
> COCKROACH_SKIP_KEY_PERMISSION_CHECK=true.

Using this information, we can change step 1.4 of the tutorial.

The default behavior gives the error you encountered:

```sh
$ cockroach cert create-client root --certs-dir=certs --ca-key=my-safe-directory/ca.key 
W210412 15:05:44.419689 1 security/certificate_loader.go:356  error finding key for certs/node.crt: key file certs/node.key has permissions -rwxrwxrwx, exceeds -rwx------
ERROR: failed to generate client certificate and key: key file certs/node.key has permissions -rwxrwxrwx, exceeds -rwx------
Failed running "cert create-client"
```

Using the `COCKROACH_SKIP_KEY_PERMISSION_CHECK=true` environment variable, we can get it to ignore the file permissions and proceed:

```sh
$ COCKROACH_SKIP_KEY_PERMISSION_CHECK=true cockroach cert create-client root --certs-dir=certs --ca-key=my-safe-directory/ca.key
```

If you do use this work-around, you will need to use it to start the `cockroach` server as well.

Comment: Running the command returns: `-bash: ./cockroach: No such file or directory`

Comment: The following worked for me: `COCKROACH_SKIP_KEY_PERMISSION_CHECK=true cockroach cert create-client root --ce
rts-dir=certs --ca-key=my-safe-directory/ca.key` . I needed to prefix `COCKROACH_SKIP_KEY_PERMISSION_CHECK=true` to start the cluster too

Comment: Sorry, I was using a local binary (not in my path), hence the `./`. I changed my answer to match the tutorial step. And yes, unless you change the permissions on the file, you will need to keep telling the `cockroach` binary to ignore the bad permissions.

Comment: I needed to prefix `COCKROACH_SKIP_KEY_PERMISSION_CHECK=true` to start the cluster too. But, it does not allow using the sql client even with the prefix. Any suggestions?

Comment: The environment variable needs to be used with `cockroach sql` as well since it's attempting to read the certificates from the same directory and will fail on the bad permissions.